# AngularJS: $watch vs controller save()

Tags: angularjs

I have a property in my angular model that needs to be calculated before sending to the server.  I have a save() method in my controller that sends the model to the $http service to save the data.  It goes something like this:

```
$scope.user.customerId = lookup($scope.user.userId);
```

Where `lookup()` looks up the value in a local array.  The customerID value is currently not used in the view at all, but the server wants the customerID.

My question is: **Is there a best practice around calculating values?**

Should this be done in a $watch, implicitly in an object getter, or should this be done while saving, either in the controller or in a service?  Something else entirely?

I appreciate any input.

Comment: Normally you don't calculate things like customerid client-side - it's done server side, and usually automatically by your DB backend.  Once you add an object to the backend, you can read the result back (containing the customer id) and assign it to your json object after it's been successfully added.

Comment: Usually perhaps.  I don't have control over the API in this case however.  It happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service would be a better choice than the controller, since `customerID` won't be used in a view.

But if `customerID` is *only* used on the server, I would recommend using a request interceptor. You can read more about it in the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Hopefully this helps:

```
module.factory('customerIdInterceptor', [function() {
  var requestInterceptor = {
    request: function(config) {
      // request payload is in config.data
      // calculate customerId and put it where you want it
    }
  };

  return requestInterceptor;
}]);

module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('customerIdInterceptor');
}]);
```